# Docker push hangs forever on Windows 10

Tags: docker, windows-10

I am running Windows 10 Professional Version 1809. Pushing docker images to docker.io takes endless time (does not finish even after several hours). On my physical Ubuntu machine in the same network pushing the same finishes in only a few seconds.

It seems this is not related to the way how I install docker. I tried Docker for Windows (using Hyper-V), Docker Machine (using VirtualBox) and also I installed Ubuntu+Docker within VirtualBox on my own. The result is always the same.

I already tried to disable Windows Defender, with no improvement at all.
Any ideas are welcome, since I am running out of ideas completely.

Comment: building and pulling is reasonable speed, only pushing hangs

Comment: Have you tried enabling debug mode (`-D`) and seeing if the output adds any more info? I've seen some posts of people having issues getting debug information from pushes, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: Yes, tried it now. The last entry in the log says "Checking for presence of layer ..." and this entry stays forever. Not very helpful unfortunately. But thanks for the hint.

Comment: Looks like that's the line spit out right before checking digests from the repo to see if the layer exists: [source](https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/blob/8a582e89b407639018e067123eb17f61dbfd10ee/components/engine/distribution/push_v2.go#L548). Nothing automatically gets printed on completion though. If you keep trying things and get really desperate you could try adding some print statements and re-running from source... Sounds like it may be something I/O related on your Windows box though.

Comment: I am getting that desparate that I will probably run the docker daemon on some remote linux machine... Docker is just not made for my Windows it seems.